# How to convert a JSON object to a Protobuf Message

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobufjs

Imagine I have the following JSON Object,

```
const json = {
    code: 3,
    message: 'Test error message',
    details: [
        {
            '@type': 'google.rpc.BadRequest',
            fieldViolations: [
                {
                    field: 'field',
                    description: 'must not be null',
                },
            ],
        },
    ],
};
```

How can it be converted to a Proto `Message` using protobufjs?